# Is there a long term solution to prevent tree shoots from coming up in lawn?

Tags: root-pruning

The shoots coming up in the middle of my lawn (see picture) I believe they are from the roots of a cherry tree that is roughly 15 feet away (I could be wrong, there is also a Pear and Maple tree nearby).

Is my only option to keep cutting them at the ground or maybe more effective to chop a wedge out of the root?

I'm general curious about controlling shoots in other areas as well. It seems like there should be a better solution then just clipping them back a few times a year. 
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It'll be the cherry tree causing the problem - these put out a lot of surface roots, from which shoots will grow - often in untended gardens, you might find what appear to be 4 young cherry trees spaced out 30 feet away from an old cherry tree, or within 30 feet of a now dead cherry tree. All these will be formed from the mature, surface roots of the original tree. Unfortunately, its the nature of these trees - there isn't really a good solution other than to plant cherry well away from any lawns, and to keep wrenching off the shoots which appear.

Answer (score 1):

It's almost certainly from one of the fruit trees.  If you really just have to clip them a few times a year, I'd just do it, unless you really don't like the tree for other reasons.  This probably isn't the answer you wanted, but there you are!

Comment: Haha, no problem Ed. The Cherry tree seems to be particularly prolific. Could the shoots be stimulated by pruning I did on the tree last fall? Or what is going on that causes trees to want to send up shoots? I knew it was a shot in the dark. I'm a new home owner and always looking for the "right" long term solutions.